# JSF: Reusing f:ajax render/execute selector

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

In JSF 2, the built in ajax tag allows pre-defined keywords to select a render or execute 
target. e.g:

```html
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@this" />
```

Is there any easy way to reuse the selector code in a custom component? e.g:

```html
<f:mycustomcomponent update="@form" />
```

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding the concrete problem. Isn't your concrete question more that you're looking for a standard JSF API method call which converts a pseudo client IDs like `@form` to an absolute client ID like `formId`?

Comment: Yes, that is really my question. I was just giving an example where that API, if it is actually an API, was already being used in JSF.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is none.

Comment: Well, that's sad. They already coded it, might as well make it an API... Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard JSF API for that with the simple reason that they are processed in the client side by the `jsf.js` script file. The JSF ajax JavaScript replaces `@form` by `element.form.id` and `@this` by `element.id` and so on. It's unclear what exactly you need it for, but if you basically need to pass it through to `jsf.ajax.request()`, then you actually don't need to manipulate it yourself.

But if you actually need it to reference some JSF components in the component tree for some reason, your best bet is really to homebrew it. Provided that you're inside an `UIComponent`, here's a kickoff example (remember that it can contain multiple values, spaceseparated)

```
if (update.charAt(0) != '@') {
    component = findComponent(update);
} else if (update.equals("@all")) {
    component = context.getViewRoot();
} else if (update.equals("@form")) {
    component = getClosestParent(this, UIForm.class);
} else if (update.equals("@none")) {
    component = null;
} else if (update.equals("@this")) {
    component = this;
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong update value " + update);
}
```

with this little helper method (copied from [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`Components` utility class](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Components))

```
public static <T extends UIComponent> T getClosestParent(UIComponent component, Class<T> parentType) {
    UIComponent parent = component.getParent();

    while (parent != null && !parentType.isInstance(parent)) {
        parent = parent.getParent();
    }

    return parentType.cast(parent);
}
```